# exclude lines from a file based on specific values in certain columns

Tags: centos, text-processing, regular-expression

I have a text file on Linux server CentOS 7 which include a lot of entries in the following format:

```
1234567890123456, 1, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 2, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 3, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 4, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 5, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 1, 18, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 1, 17, cde, Test Test
```

which command shall I use to remove

```
1, 17
2, 17
3, 17
4, 17
```

so the result should be

```
1234567890123456, 5, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 1, 18, cde, Test Test
```

Comment: what's special about the lines to remove? Just those exact values, or is there some formula?

Comment: @JeffSchaller exact values.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '!($2<5 && $3==17)' file
```

The output:

```
1234567890123456, 5, 17, cde, Test Test
1234567890123456, 1, 18, cde, Test Test
```

---

- `-F,` - field separator
- `$2`, `$3` - represent the 2nd and the 3rd field respectively

Answer (score 1):

To exclude those exact values, taking advantage of the commonality that the field-3 exclusion is always '17':

```
awk -F, '!($3 == 17 && ($2 == 1 || $2 == 2 || $2 == 3 || $2 == 4))' < input > output
```